# Is the following bilinear form positive

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Let $B:V\times  V\rightarrow \mathbb R$ where $V$ is all the polynomials with degree $\leq2$.

Determine whether the following is positive $\langle f,g\rangle =\int^1_0f(x)g(x)xdx$.

I tried refuting it, but I'm not really sure its not true. I can't see how to prove it though.

P.S. The definition of positive bilinear form is for every $v\in V \neq 0$,

$0\leq \langle v,v\rangle $

Comment: Great, you tried something. How about you tell us what the something is? Maybe you're close!

Comment: I tried $f(x)=x-1$, and other vartiations. The question is that I'm not sure whether the degree can be lower than 1.

Comment: Hint: Let $f$ and $g$ be polynomials of degree less than 2. Surely you can compute their inner product as a function of their coefficients and try to figure out more about this bilinear form

Comment: @Jim You said you need to determine if $\langle v,v\rangle\geq 0$. Then why don't you check *that*? With the $f$, it's just $\langle f,f\rangle$, which you check to see is or isn't always at least $0$. This is the very first thing you should do to try to prove it. If you had problems, you'd start looking for counterexamples, but here there's no excuse for not trying the direct proof first.

Comment: 1) positive definite means $\langle v, v\rangle > 0$ for all $v \ne 0$. 2) For any continuous function $f$ on $[0,1]$, if it is not identical zero, then $\int_0^1 f(x)^2 dx > 0$.

Comment: Notice it's $f(x)g(x)x$... That's the issue.

Comment: Look carefully at your definition of positive definite. The same $v$ appear in both sides of $\langle v, v\rangle$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $0 \ne f(x) \in V$, consider $\langle f, f \rangle = \int_0^1 (f(x))^2 x  dx$.  Since $f(x) \ne 0$, we have $(f(x))^2 x \ge 0$ everywhere on $[0, 1]$ and $(f(x))^2 x > 0$ *somewhere* in the interior $(0, 1)$ of this interval.  If $(f(x_0))^2 x_0 > 0$ for $x_0 \in (0, 1)$, by continuity of $(f(x))^2 x$ there exists an open interval $(a, b) =I \subset [0, 1]$ with $x_0 \in I$ and $(f(x))^2 x > m >0$ on $I$ for some real $m$ with $0< m < (f(x_0))^2 x_0$.  Then we  must have $ \int_0^1 (f(x))^2 x dx \ge m(b - a) > 0$, showing that $\langle f, f \rangle > 0$; thus $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is positive. ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Happy New Year,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You said you want to check if $\langle f,f\rangle\geq 0$ holds.

That would be $\int_0^1f(x)^2x dx\geq 0$, by the definition you gave.

Is the integral of $f(x)^2x$ on $[0,1]$ nonnegative?! It would be if, say $f(x)^2x$ were a nonnegative function...